# Find a sequence of bytes in memory using lldb

Tags: lldb

I'm trying to locate a specific sequence of bytes within an AAC audio stream.  When I test lldb's memory find -s command I can see it doesn't allow me to specify escaped octal characters.  How do I search for an arbitrary sequence of bytes?

Here's my test:

```
(lldb) x -c 1024 avpkt->data
0x101500180: 21 08 d4 e5 89 3e 22 ee 45 a2 40 a5 02 41 14 0a  !....>".E.@..A..
0x101500190: f2 a3 2b d1 a5 7d c4 f9 f3 11 75 2c 17 47 4e 50  ..+..}....u,.GNP
0x1015001a0: 03 23 3d 02 77 5b 7b ef 89 07 13 45 0a 16 4a 54  .#=.w[{....E..JT
...
(lldb) memory find -s "\010\324\345\211\076\042" -- 0x101500180 0x101500580
data not found within the range.
```

where 08 d4 e5 89 3e 22 (the 6 byte sequence starting at 0x101500181) in octal is 0010 0324 0345 0211 0076 0042